# I need to remove Y-axis labels on highcharts while keeping the data intact

Tags: highcharts

I'm looking to correct some y-Axis issues. I'm looking to remove, or edit, the left and right axis-labels and keep the middle one. [the 0 - 2400 label and remove, or edit, the 0-72g and 0-2400m]

In doing so, I also want to keep all the data intact, however not the labels.

here's my JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/codkare17/L7w67znv/5/

```
function createChart() {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        thousandsSep: ','
    }
});

  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 4
    },

    yAxis: [{
      labels: {
       min: 0,
       max: 8000
      },
      title: {
        text: "Price (USD)",
         formatter: '${value}'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 2,
        color: 'silver'
      }]
    }, {}, {}],

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        showInNavigator: false
      }
    },

    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> <br/>',
      valueDecimals: 2,
      split: true   
    },

    series: seriesOptions
  });
}


$.getJSON('https://www.coincap.io/history/365day/BTC', function(json) {
  console.log(json)
  $.each(names, function(i, name) {

    seriesOptions.push({
      name: name,
      data: json[name],
      type: name === 'volume' ? 'column' : 'line',
      yAxis: i
    })
  });

  createChart()
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change yAxis' `visible` property to false: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/L7w67znv/6/